# How to display a simple wicket message with one simple parameter with StringResourceModel

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I have one Wicket text property in the WicketApplicationProperties.properies

```
 <entry key="dataMniejszaNizMinimalna">Wybrano datę, która jest mniejsza niż minimalna akceptowalna data '${minimalnaData}'. Nie można zapisać danych."</entry>
```

How to substitute a parameter {minimalnaData} with a use of a class
StringResourceModel. I don't want to create any models i want to just display a message with provided one attribute. The Wicket StringResourceModel is so complicated.

```
new StringResourceModel(resourceKey).setParameters(params)
```

how to provide this one parameter is a simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way could be:

```
new StringResourceModel(resourceKey, this, Model.ofMap(Map.of("minimalnaData", "some value")))
```

The model object could be a Java Bean or a java.util.Map.

StringResourceModel also supports java.text.MessageFormat. You can use its `#setParameters()` method to pass an array of values for the placeholders.

Comment: It works fine, thanks but I had to change from Model.of to Model.ofMap

Comment: I've updated my answer! Thank you and have fun with Apache Wicket!

Answer (score 1):

I think wicket:message should fit your need. Take a look at the wiki:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket%27s+XHTML+tags

You can nest components within textual content.